# Trouble with overlapping labels (geom_text)

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

Trouble with overlapping geom_text labels on pie chart

```
library(scales)
blank_theme <- theme_minimal()+
theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title=element_text(size=14, face="bold")
)


df6 <- data.frame(group = c("Seedling","Ground", "Fern", "Moss"),value = c(2.125,80.125, 11.376,6.375))
# Create a basic bar
pie6 = ggplot(df6, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) + blank_theme + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())

# Convert to pie (polar coordinates) and add labels
pie6 = pie6 + coord_polar("y", start=0) + geom_text(aes( label = paste0((value), "%")),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))


# Remove labels and add title
pie6 = pie6 + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, title = "Understory Composition, Site 2")

# Tidy up the theme
pie6 = pie6 + theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                                  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                                  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "black"))

pie6
```

[image]

This is my current output. How can i change the labels such that they do not overlap? i have tried various hjust and vjust, positions and position_stack but to no avail

Any help appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the package ggrepel? If so I recommend. It automatically stops labels overlapping and finds a fit for each other them.

```
#Install ggrepel package
install.packages("ggrepel", dependencies=TRUE)


df6 <- data.frame(group = c("Seedling","Ground", "Fern", "Moss"),value = c(2.125,80.125, 11.376,6.375))
# Create a basic bar
pie6 = ggplot(df6, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", 
width=1) + blank_theme + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())

# Convert to pie (polar coordinates) and add labels using ggrepel
pie6 = pie6 + coord_polar("y", start=0) + ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes( label = 
paste0((value), "%")),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))


# Remove labels and add title
pie6 = pie6 + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, title = "Understory Composition, Site 2")

# Tidy up the theme
pie6 = pie6 + theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                                  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                                  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "black"))

pie6
```

Comment: your code works with 2 modifications: add `library(ggrepel)` and change `blank_theme` with `theme_minimal()`

Answer (score 2):

A manual approach to this problem could be to manipulate the orientation of the text by setting the `angle` parameter in the  `geom_text` function. This allows you to set the orientation of all text fragments at once by assigning a singel value to angle. You may also set the angle for the individual text items as illustrated below.

```
ggplot(df6, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) + 
  blank_theme +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0((value), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            angle = c(-90, -90, 0, -90))              ####### here
```

[image]

The code below adjust the angle depending on the pie it describes.

```
ggplot(df6, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) + 
  blank_theme +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0((value), "%")), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            angle = c(-97, -110, 0, -70))             ####### here
```

[image]

Another way to work around the problem you state, is to play with the `start` parameter of the `coord_polar` function:

```
ggplot(df6, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 180) +               ####### here
  blank_theme +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0((value), "%")) , 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]